# Python - Kivy framework - Spinner values list

Tags: python, list, templates, spinner, kivy

I'm having tough times adding list of values (languages) that I extract from my db and want it to be available as a values list in Spinner widget.

python part:

```
 def get_langs(self):
        session = Session()
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        # get active language as text label:
        result1 = session.query(Language).filter_by(active = 1).first()
        self.label_lang.text = str(result1)
        # get all other languages as list of values:
        result2 = session.query(Language).filter_by(active = 0).all()
        self.label_lang.values = str(result2)
```

kv template part:

```
Spinner:
    id: settings_lang
    size_hint: (None, None)
    width: 200
    height: 40
    padding_left: 20
    self: root.get_langs()
```

I am extracting a list of values from my db (via sqlalchemy) but the "values" attribute in kv template is accepting only str/unicode therefore str(result2). However, instead of list of languages I get list of the characters within that list.

[
E
n
g
l
i
s
h
,

D
e
u
t
s
c
h
]

but I want to see these as values:
English
Deutsch

Can anyone advise?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting your results to a single string, instead of a list of strings.

```
self.label_lang.values = map(str, result2)
```

Is probably what you want instead.

Comment: ok, done (that was my very first question so I didn't know about that...). I will upvote also once I get some reputation points. Thanks again.